# Not able to cluster square matrix with more than 317 rows and columns using k-means?

Tags: matlab, k-means

I have a 1750-by-1750 matrix, `Y`. I want to cluster it into 50 clusters using k-means. My code is:

```
[idx,C] = kmeans(Y,50)
```

However, I keep getting an error:

> Error using kmeans (line 243)
>   X must have more rows than the number of clusters.

Why? What is going on?

I reduced the size of the matrix and, by trial and error, I figured out that the error does not show until the matrix size is 317-by-317. Beyond that, from 318-by-318 and upwards, it starts throwing the error.

Comment: For `kmeans`, the number of rows determines the number of samples and the number of columns denote the number of features for each point.  What exactly does `Y` represent?

Comment: @rayryeng Hello. `Y` is a matrix that I made from some unrelated calculations. It contains the similarity between 1750 images. Now I want to cluster them into 50 clusters based on their similarity values (from matrix `Y`).

Comment: Have you checked the values in the 318th row and column? If a column is all `NaN` for some reason you will get exactly this error (and a warning too: "Warning: Ignoring rows of X with missing data."), e.g., `A=rand(10);` `A(:,5)=NaN;` `kmeans(A,3)`.

Comment: @horchler Aah, you hit the nail on the head. It should have come to my mind to check this. It is indeed the case.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your data matrix `Y` doesn't have any columns that consist of only `NaN` values. You can start with the 318th column because you know that its inclusion results in an error. Using [`isnan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isnan.html) and [`all`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/all.html):

```
all(isnan(Y(:,318))
```

You can check all columns of your input data matrix via:

```
find(all(isNaN(Y)))
```

which will return the indices of any columns that are all `NaN`.